# get latest record against foreign key and check whether its specific column has value NULL or not

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Hi I am working on a project Laravel where I need to update record in database by fetching last(latest) record against foreign key, The scenario is fetch latest record(row) and if its specific column (amendments_to) has NULL value update it with some string else insert a new record. Below is my code what it does is always updates last row only no matter what the value in amendments_to column is.

```
OrderResponse::where('send_id', $id)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->take(1)
    ->update(['amendments_to' => $request->comment]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only are doing it with a single row at a time, i would simply do a more `Eloquent` approach. `Laravel` has a helper for `latest()` query.

```
$orderResponse = OrderResponse::where('send_id', $id)
    ->latest()
    ->first();

if (!$orderResponse->amendments_to) {
    $orderResponse->amendments_to = $request->comment;
    $orderResponse->save();
} else {
    $newOrderResponse = new OrderResponse([
        'amendments_to' => $request->comment,
        'send_id' => $id,
        // other fields
    ]);
    $newOrderResponse->save();
}
```

Comment: Will that work without doing `take(1)->first()`? `$orderResponse` is still just a `Builder` object here.

Comment: You are right, assumed take 1 was a query builder resolver, similar to first()

Comment: It's just an alias to `limit`, just like `take` is an alias to `offset`. Also, I think `latest` might not be the best method since it won't always give the same results as `orderBy('id', 'desc')`. (If I remember correctly `latest()` is an alias to  `orderByDesc('updated_at')`)

Comment: Have you changed it to use first()? the code got updated based on the comment :)

Comment: Hi @mrhn thanks for your response your code snippet update last (latest) record whether there is NULL in amendment_to column or value is present there what I am actually looking for is if in last record amendments_to column has NULL value update it with  upcoming request otherwise add a new row(record)

Comment: @mrhn and I had change it to first() as well

Comment: Added the logic you wanted

Comment: did my added logic help your problem?